# Nest an inline template inside of a .vue component

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I've got an inline template that I've used already with Laravel's Blade `@include('my_inline_template')` that works great.

Now, I've pulled in another vue component that someone else developed and uses the .vue file format.  I would like to put my inline template inside of that .vue file.

What I want to do is something like the below, which doesn't work because you can't use `@include` within a .vue file.  I'm kind of stuck as to what else to try, or if this is even possible:

**main-vue.js**

```
import Component from './components/Component.vue'
require('./components/my_inline_template');
const vm = new Vue({
    el: '#vue_root',

    components: {
        Component
    }
});
```

**my_inline_template.js**

```
Vue.component('my_inline_template', {
    // blah
});
```

**my_inline_template.blade.php**

```
<my_inline_template inline-template>
   // blah
</my_inline_template
```

**Component.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
         @include('my_inline_template')
         // More HTML 
    </div>
</template>

<script>

    export default{
        props: ['blah'],

        data() {
            return{
                // blah
                },
        },

        mounted() {
            // blah
        },

        methods: {
            // blah
        }
    }
</script>
```

How can I include `my_inline_template` in the above .vue file?  Thanks!

Comment: "I've got an inline template that I've used already with Laravel's Blade @include('my_inline_template') that works great." - can you show how you did it?

Comment: @riyaz-ali If you look at my_inline_template.blade.php and my_inline_template.blade.js above, and if you see how I've registered this component in main-vue.js, then you can include it with another blade.php file by simply using @include('my_inline_template').  However, as my question here states, I don't now how or if it's even possible to use this template in a .vue file.

Comment: Well that's what I am asking....in your my_inline_template.js file how do you add your template? via a url pointing to my_inline_template.blade.php? you could probably add some more details on how you load the template in your code above...

Comment: The way it works is that main-vue.js brings in the my_inline_template.js javascript.  Then main-vue.js gets compiled by elixir and included on the web page like this:  `<script src="{{ elixir('main-vue.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>`so whenever I use @include('my_inline_template') in any blade file, this pulls in the blade file containing the inline template.  That all works fine in the app with blade files, but (obviously) the .vue file doesn't like trying to include the blade file containing the inline template.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by separating out the components into several smaller components.  This way, I could have the .vue component and the inline template next to each other on the same blade view. However, it's not really an answer to my question, so if someone would like to offer an answer I'd still be grateful.

My guess is you can't nest an inline template that makes use of blade inside of a .vue file.